# spring boot startup error BOOT-INF/classes not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a spring boot project

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {GsonAutoConfiguration.class})
    public class TranslationApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TranslationApplication.class, args);
    }
     @Bean
    public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
            LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
           factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("CIT_DEV");
    return factoryBean;
    }
}
```

I use

```
 EntityManager em = localEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject().createEntityManager();
```

to get `EntityManager` instance

There is `CIT_DEV` persistence unit in persistence.xml under META-INF folder

I use gradle bootJar to generate jar file, in the jar BOOT-INF/classes/META-INF has persistence.xml

and I use java -jar jarFile to start the spring boot, it throws error

```
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:220) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:150) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
 at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:166) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
 at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:103) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
 at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.resolveJarFileReference(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:168) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:51) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:47) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:76) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:99) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:232) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:174) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:76) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:171) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:119) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:61) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:50) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar!/:5.3.7.Final]
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79) [javaee-api-8.0.jar!/:na]
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:96) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$87/1170794006.getObject(Unknown Source) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1244) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$87/1170794006.getObject(Unknown Source) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) [spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) [spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) [spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
 at oracle.cit.translation.TranslationApplication.main(TranslationApplication.java:18) [classes!/:na]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40-ea]
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [cit-trans-microservice-1.0.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [cit-trans-microservice-1.0.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [cit-trans-microservice-1.0.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [cit-trans-microservice-1.0.jar:na]
```

Comment: It's hard to help without a complete view of what you're trying to do. Could you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people trying to help have everything they need to reproduce the problem that you have? It would also be useful to provide the complete stack trace of the exception that is occurring. It looks like it's truncated at the moment.

Comment: Hi, Andy, if you create the above class, and create persistence.xml under META-INF folder in classpath, then create a jar for your project, and run "java -jar jarFileName", you will hit the above error

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have time to piece things together and guess about the parts that you haven't shared. For example, I don't know what dependencies your application has or what versions of those dependencies you are using. If you'd like me to help, or to increase the chances of someone else having the time to help, please take the time to provide a complete example of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
@Autowired
EntityManager em;
```

It's managed by springboot.

Comment: I added  @Autowired
 public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean localEntityManagerFactoryBean; in RestController class, and use EntityManager em = localEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject().createEntityManager(); it still has the error

Comment: @Autowired
EntityManager em; does not work, how to define a EntityManager BEAN?

Comment: You need to delete bean definition for `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean`

Comment: Field em in oracle.cit.translation.rest.CITTransResource required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' that could not be found.,  how to write a bean for EntityManager. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html

Spring Boot will not search for or use a META-INF/persistence.xml by default. If you prefer to use a traditional persistence.xml, you need to define your own @Bean of type LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean (with an ID of ‘entityManagerFactory’) and set the persistence unit name there.

I use this way, but it still has the filenotfound exception